# Generating a sequential date time in Java

Tags: java

I want to create a sequential date time generator in Java which is required for performance testing within a boundary of start date and end date.
I am using Jmeter for this testing and each thread should get a unique date time value.
For e.g. For Start Date: 2018-11-01 00:00:00 End Date: 2018-11-10 23:59:59

```
1st Value= 2018-11-01 00:00:00
2nd Value = 2018-11-01 00:00:01
3rd Value = 2018-11-01 00:00:02
....
....
....
61st Value = 2018-11-01 00:01:00
62nd Value = 2018-11-01 00:01:01
....
....
And so on.
```

Any idea on how this can be implemented?

Comment: Have a look at the `LocalDateTime` class and its method `plusSeconds`.

Answer (score 0):

**use TimerTask class** 
set date format as per your requirement.

```
class Demo extends TimerTask {
public void run() {
   System.out.println( new Date()); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new Demo(), 0, 1000);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `LocalDateTime` iterator using Streams:

```java
  public static Iterator<LocalDateTime> dateTimeIterator(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {
        return LongStream.range(0L, Duration.between(start, end).getSeconds()+1).mapToObj(start::plusSeconds).iterator();
  }

  static final Iterator<LocalDateTime> testDateTimeIterator = dateTimeIterator(
    LocalDateTime.of(2018,11,1,0,0,0),
    LocalDateTime.of(2018,11,1,0,1,1)
  );
```

and invoke `testDateTimeIterator.next()` once per test. You may add some synchronization control, but I think it wouldn't be necessary.